# The equivalent of a piece of PHP code in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I need to implement a payment port in Python. Here I have to encrypt a string and send it to the server and get a response. I have the equivalent of this piece of code in PHP.But I want this function in Python. I mention my efforts. I also set the value of the key. I've also shown incoming errors. Thank you for advising.Below is the PHP code:

```
function encrypt_pkcs7 ($str, $key)
{
$key = base64_decode($key);
$cipherText = OpenSSL_encrypt($str, "DES-EDE3", $key, 
OPENSSL_RAW_DATA);
return base64_encode($cipherText);
}
```

My attempt at Python.

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3
def encrypt_DES3(terminal_id,order_id,amount):
    """

    :param terminal_id: String-for example: EUDuTQrp
    :param order_id: integer- for example: 123456
    :param amount: integer - for example: 60000
    :return: encrypt "terminal_id;oreder_id;integer"
    """
    key =base64.b64decode("YTAzZTYyNDNiMTljMzg0YzYxY2NhMGU4NjU1ODc2N2FkYTAwMGJiOQ==")
    text = terminal_id + ';' + str(order_id) + ';' + str(amount)
    def pad(text):
        while len(text) % 8 != 0:
            text += '='
        return text

    plain_text = pad(plain_text)
    cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
    my_export = cipher.encrypt(plain_text)

    return my_export
```

The error I get:

```
File "<pyshell#18>", line 1, in <module>
encrypt_DES3('EUDuTQrp',123456,60000)
File "<pyshell#17>", line 17, in encrypt_DES3
cipher = DES3.new(key, DES3.MODE_ECB)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 
113, in new
return DES3Cipher(key, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/DES3.py", line 
76, in __init__
blockalgo.BlockAlgo.__init__(self, _DES3, key, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/Crypto/Cipher/blockalgo.py", 
line 141, in __init__
self._cipher = factory.new(key, *args, **kwargs)
ValueError: Invalid key size (must be either 16 or 24 bytes long)
```

Comment: I don't see any indentation below `encrypt_DES3`

Comment: i have correctly formatted it now. And formatting is not the error as the Exception raised is ValueError Invalid key size. @AlbertoPoljak

Comment: By the way the code for padding you have written pads in block sizes of 8. you can simply change the 8 to 16 or 24 which is the size needed by DES. ;)

Comment: i think this code is for sadad. How did you implement it? in my case generate different code in php and django.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import DES3

def pad(text,pad_size=16):
    text_length = len(text)
    last_block_size = text_length % pad_size
    remaining_space = pad_size - last_block_size

    text = text + '='*remaining_space

    return text

def encrypt_DES3(terminal_id,order_id,amount):
    """

    :param terminal_id: String-for example: EUDuTQrp
    :param order_id: integer- for example: 123456
    :param amount: integer - for example: 60000
    :return: encrypt "terminal_id;oreder_id;integer"
    """
    secret_key_text = "YTAzZTYyND122331"   ## you can only have key of size 16 or 24
    text = terminal_id + ';' + str(order_id) + ';' + str(amount)
    text = pad(text,8)
    cipher = DES3.new(secret_key_text, DES3.MODE_ECB)
    my_export = cipher.encrypt(text)

    return my_export
```

Comment: This will work. All you need to do is call the function as pad(text) or pad(text,24) for valid key size padding for DES encryption

Comment: ValueError: Invalid key size (must be either 16 or 24 bytes long)

Comment: what?? i did not get you. Please refrain from short and brief comments

Comment: I changed the value to 8, 16, and 24, but I got the error again. The error is related to the size of the key, which has a constant value. The string is variable and error free.When the key value is decrypted, it is 40 bytes long. Currently, the key is 56 characters or bytes. Thanks for the help.

Comment: this one worked on python3.6. I hope this works for you

Comment: OK. It works. Just one question: is this key the same previous key? Because if the key is different, the bank does not send the correct response.

Comment: here was the problem. Your key "YTAzZTYyNDNiMTljMzg0YzYxY2NhMGU4NjU1ODc2N2FkYTAwMGJiOQ=="         is 56 characters long  when you do base64.b64decode(text) it becomes of length 40. and you use this as your key but DES expects you provide a key either of length 16 or 24 bytes long. Hope it fixes your issue

Comment: also you need to provide more details. As i dont know how you are interacting with the bank. Also the php send the data in base64 encoded form while your text is just encrypted.

Comment: Is there a way to convert that key to a value of 16 or 24 bytes? That is the equivalent of that key?

Comment: To be honest, I dont know a lot of details. You should have atleast added a tag for encryption.  By the way you can run php from python. I am leaving a link for that. so just make a python file for now and run the php code from there if it works or better ask someone from encryption background, cause i am pretty sure the DES-EDE3 is not equivalent to EDE3. not sure by the way. Here's the link  https://www.quora.com/How-can-a-PHP-script-communicate-with-a-Python-script-on-the-same-Apache-web-server

Comment: True, here I have to send with base64. My last sentence is as follows:return base24.encode(my_export)   . I read everywhere that the input of the DES3 algorithm is 56 bytes or ... .This is the key to me now, it's 56 bytes. I doubt that there is another function in Python to get that key exactly.

Comment: how did you resolve this issue?  I have the same exactly